# Comboboxes visual basic 6

Tags: sql-server, vb6

I have multiple comboboxes where users have the option of selecting an item. If no item is selected I insert NULL into SQL-SERVER:

```
if cboSchool.text="" then
g_strSQL = g_strSQL & "NULL,"
else
g_strSQL = g_strSQL & "'" & cboschool.itemdata(cboschool.listindex) & "',"
End if
```

My problem is as follow: Later on I allow the user to edit the information that they previously didn't select. So later on when they want to edit the information, I need to be able to have the application realize that there was a value or there wasn't a value in the table in (SQLSERVER), compare if its different from the value that was selected. And if the information is different then need to update the table. This is what my code looks for EDIT:

```
If g_RS!SchoolID <>cboSchool.ItemData(cboSchool.ListIndex)Then
    g_strSQL2 = g_strSQL2 & " School ID = '" & cboSchool.ItemData (cboSchool.ListIndex) & "',"
End If
```

The problem Im seeing is that g_RS!SCHOOLID shows as "NULL", however it does notice that the value is different from cboschool.itemdata and it just skips to the end of the if statement. I don't understand how it doesn't see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Val("" & g_RS!SchoolID) <> cboSchool.ItemData(cboSchool.ListIndex) Then
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

It's *because* of the null value that it doesn't see a difference.

You could have:

```
If g_RS!SchoolID <> "Hello world!" Then
    g_strSQL2 = "DROP TABLE X"
Else
    MsgBox ("g_RS!SchoolID = Hello world!")
End If
```

and as long as SchoolID is NULL you'd get a messagebox.

You could fix this with something like:

```
If Iif(IsNull(g_RS!SchoolID), "", g_RS!SchoolID) <> cboSchool.ItemData(cboSchool.ListIndex) Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. I won't be able to try to this until tomorrow.